# ZipException: duplicate entry: org/webkit/android_jsc/R.class

Tags: android, react-native

I have made some changes in the android folder of react-native from that time onwards its not building

```
    app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/webkit/android_jsc/R.class
```

I have updated my build.gradle.

```
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.daddyapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':rn-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-system-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-share-menu')
    compile project(':react-native-android-sms')
    compile project(':react-native-material-kit')
    compile project(':react-native-fileupload')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
```

I have changed android folder through git but they are 2 separate codes. I don't get it why this error is coming

Comment: Can i see your app build.gradle file?

Comment: @SunilKumar updated the codes..